# Browserify/Babelify React for production (NODE_ENV production)

Tags: javascript, build, reactjs, browserify

I run this command:

```
browserify src.js -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] > build.js
```

and I get a single file that can be used by it's own. Works fine, but it's NODE_ENV is set to development and I get a console.log about downloading React DevTools.

How do I set it to production? I browsed around and didn't find anything that worked for me. I tried envify, but no luck (I'm very newb with JS builds).

I tried putting --NODE_ENV production somewhere in the line above, but I'm very new to browserify and babelify so I'm basically doing a trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `NODE_ENV` as production.

My production script usually looks something like this, nothing too spectacular

```
NODE_PATH=./src/components:./src NODE_ENV=production browserify ./src/app.js --extension .jsx -t babelify -t brfs | uglifyjs > ./dist/main.js
```

Note that this does not require `envify`, although the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#npm) suggests that it should. You can test this simply by changing the `NODE_ENV` to something else, anything else and React throws the devtools warning, but with `production` set it does not even though `envify` is not included in the transforms. There may be a better way of testing whether React is in production mode, or the documentation may not be up to date, this is tested with React 0.14.0.

*edit* React specifies its own `browserify` config which adds the `envify` transform, hence why it works. I have kept the above paragraph untouched as it is not immediately obvious why this all works, and this paragraph hopefully clears it up.

Comment: Thanks. However, it's not working for me (in the sense "I'm not doing it right"). When I run that line on my source, it breaks on the first call of <MyComponent /> within the code. When I run it on the browserified file, I get "Cannot find module './ReactMount'". Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try stripping it down, remove the `NODE_PATH` and remove the `brfs` transform. I have edited the script, but only because I put `prod` in there instead of `production`

Comment: oh, its probably the babel specification, I use a `.babelrc` file to control babel, you'll need to append your preset for babel. Either create a `.babelrc` or simply add it to the script as you have done in your example. The `NODE_PATH` and `brfs` shouldnt break anything in your build even if they are unnecessary.

Comment: Or this: `NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] -g uglifyify main.jsx -o bundle.js`